# How to find a probility that the sample mean of a population lies in a particular range?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Assume that X is a random variable with mean `x_mean` and standard deviation `x_sd`. If we take a sample of `n` items from a population at random, what is the probability that this sample mean (say `sample_x_mean`) lies between `left` and `right` values?

Comment: what are left and right?

Comment: left and right could be any values. e.g. what is the probability that `sample_x_mean` lies between 10 (`left`) and 20(`right`)?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of the sample mean $X_n$ is approximately normal with parameters $μ=x_{mean}$ and $σ/\sqrt{n}=x_{sd}/\sqrt{n}$, in symbols $$X_n \sim N\left(μ, \dfrac{σ}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$ approximately (where the approximation is better as $n$ grows to $\infty$). This follows from the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) and you do not need any further particular assumptions on the distribution of the population from which you are sampling.

Comment: Yes I thought of `CLT` at first. So `sample_x_mean` will follow a normal distribution with `x_mean` as mean and `x_sd / sqrt(n)` as standard deviation. So do I find a probability of a value, drawn at random, being in range `(left, right)` for such distribution?

Comment: Since the distribution is normal (approximately) just use the tables of the standard normal distribution. Do you know how to calculate probabilities under the normal distribution, or not?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. (y)

Comment: You are welcome